# Integer to String representation of int n expressed in base b

Tags: java, string, recursion

So i created this program that takes an int and returns its octal number.
Now if I wanted to created a recursive function that returns a string representation of an integer n expressed in base b, how would I do that.

```
static void displayOctal(int n) { //n = 100
   if(n>0) {
      if(n/8>0) {
         displayOctal(n/8);
      }
      System.out.println(n%8); //prints 144
   }
}
```

This is what is have so have so far. I am way off, i know.

```
static String integerToString(int n, int b) { //100, 8
   if(n > 0) {
      if(n/b > 0) {
       String s = integerToString(n%b, b) + integerToString(n/b, b)
   }
   else
     return integerToString(
```

Comment: By calling [`Integer.toString(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-int-) which does that.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your code doesn't quite work. It should go something like:

1. if `n < b`, then return `b`.
2. else return `integertoString(n/b, b)` + `b`

Also you have to add something to represent digits past `9` (i.e. A, B, C...). For example, you could have an array of valid digits, or a method.

This code would work:

```
static String[] digits = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};

static String integerToString(int n, int b) {
    if(n < b) return digits[n];
    else return integerToString(n/b, b) + digits[n%b];
}
```

For example, `integerToString(255, 16)`, outputs `FF`
Note that you should use `StringBuilder` to make it more efficient.

Comment: I would use a long `String` and call `charAt` instead of defining an array.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Sure, except it would fail past base 36

Comment: You would need to make up your own symbols for larger bases. Note: minutes and seconds are base 60.

Comment: @PeterLawrey and days are base 365.25, kind of

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use recursion you have to

- work out your stop condition, i.e. what is the minimum you can handle.
- work how you take a piece of work can call itself with less work.

.

```
String letters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
public static String integerToString(int n, int b) {
    return n < b 
           ? letters.charAt(n, b) // one digit
           : integerToString(n/b, b) + letters.charAt(n % b, b); // more than one
}
```

This will work for base 2 to 36.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String convert(int number, int base)
{
    int quotient = number / base;
    int remainder = number % base;

    if(quotient == 0) // base case
    {
        return Integer.toString(remainder);      
    }
    else
    {
        return convert(quotient, base) + Integer.toString(remainder);
    }            
}
```